# Перемещение элемента

Tags: jquery, animate, html5, css

К примеру, есть такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".phone-keys").click(function(){
    $(this).css('position', 'relative');
    $(this).animate({'left':'-200px'}, 2000);
});
```

Он просто по клику на элемент передвигает его влево на 200px. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы он по повторному клику возвращался обратно или по клику вне этого элемента?!

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('*').on('click', function(){
    $('.moved').animate({'left':'0'}, 2000, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('moved');
    });
});
$(".phone-keys").not('.moved').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('position', 'relative').animate({'left':'-200px'}, 2000, function(){
        $(this).addClass('moved');
    });
});
```

});

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/eo7okLdy/)

Comment: спасибо огромное.